# Connecting to Hyperledger Fabric blockchain using React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hyperledger-fabric

are there any working examples that connects client application developed using React Native to Hyperledger Fabric 2.4? Found a [wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hlf-wrapper) but it's targeted at HLF 1.4 and built only for Android. Most examples are built for Node.js but doesn't work for RN.